# Request parameters and requestscoped bean usage

Tags: jsf

I would like to use a few `@RequestScoped` beans to make some simple business logic on my entities. In their `@PostContruct` method, I obtain the id of the entity from the request parameters map.

This kind of setup works well for creating streamed graphics contents, using something like the following (in this case part of a composite component):

```
<p:graphicImage value="#{myRequestScopedBean.picture}" >
      <f:param name="entityId"
               value="#{cc.attrs.value.id}" />
</p:graphicImage>
```

However, the `<f:param>` tag does not seem to work for all components. For instance, how am I supposed to pass them in a `<ui:repeat>`, `<c:set>`, or to call my bean method for any of the other attributes than `value`?